# Is it possible to 'losslessly' crop a macroblock-based video stream such as h.264?

Tags: video, h.264, crop, codec

I'd like to 'losslessly' (ie, without transcoding) crop a video I have encoded using h.264. Is this possible?

I don't know in detail how h.264 works, but I understand the general principles (macroblocks, I-frames, optical flow/pushing groups of pixels around). In my imagination a crop operation (restricted to macroblock boundaries) could simply shave off the unneeded macroblocks leaving a smaller picture frame, updating the packet metadata to match. Would this work?

[edit] I want to be able to do this server-side, so cropping on display is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

No its not exactly cropping macro blocks, you have to decode the entire frame, then you can display only the part you want to see (cropping using display functions). In case you are transmitting it, then you need to transmit the entire frame as it is and do the above at the far end.

Comment: Thanks, but as per my edit of the question, I want to be able to do this on a server.